# Pseudocode for Hashing Operation

Tags: java, hashtable

I am studying the book `Data Structures Problem Solving Using Java` and have been asked to provide detailed pseudocode for line #5 of a given function in the book. Apparently line #5 is equivalent to the addition and shifting of a 16-bit binary number but I do not understand how that works.

I come from a basic Java background and understand line #5 as a stored variable multiplied by 37 and added with the current letter the loop has iterated onto (which I'm assuming is then converted to an ASCII character when it's added to the `int` `hashVal`).

```
public static int hash( String key, int tableSize ) {
    int hashVal = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < key.length( ); i++ )
        hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key.charAt( i ); // line 5

    hashVal %= tableSize;
    if( hashVal < 0 )
        hashVal += tableSize;

    return hashVal;
}
```

Can anybody help explain to me how line #5 and the addition and shifting of a 16-bit binary number are related? In other words, how can line #5 be described in pseudocode to suit that definition?

Comment: Nothing to do with 16-bit numbers.  37 = 26 letters + 10 digits + 1 other char and is also prime, so generates a well-distributed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They might be referring to the implicit conversion of `key.charAt(i)` into an `int`; `char`s are internally represented as 16-bit numbers.  That's all -- that's just how `char`s are represented and converted to `int`s.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html for details:

> The char data type (and therefore the value that a Character object encapsulates) are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities. The Unicode Standard has since been changed to allow for characters whose representation requires more than 16 bits. The range of legal code points is now U+0000 to U+10FFFF, known as Unicode scalar value. (Refer to the definition of the U+n notation in the Unicode Standard.)